# Looking for a dual of ReaderT, which abstracts over the environment instead of monadic result

Tags: haskell

Is the following abstraction with instances of `Contravariant`, `Divisible` and etc. already implemented in some package? I imply something in the spirit of the following compilable code:

```
newtype ReaderDual a m b =
  ReaderDual (b -> m a)

instance Contravariant (ReaderDual a m) where
  contramap ba (ReaderDual a') =
    ReaderDual $ a' . ba

instance (Applicative m, Monoid a) => Divisible (ReaderDual a m) where
  divide aToBC (ReaderDual b') (ReaderDual c') =
    ReaderDual $ \a -> aToBC a & \(b, c) -> (<>) <$> b' b <*> c' c
  conquer =
    ReaderDual $ \_ -> pure mempty

run :: ReaderDual a m b -> b -> m a
run (ReaderDual a') b =
  a' b
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can build this type as a composition of [`Op`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/contravariant-1.3.2/docs/Data-Functor-Contravariant.html#t:Op) from `contravariant` and [`Ap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reducers-3.10.3.2/docs/Data-Semigroup-Applicative.html#v:Ap) from `reducers`. `Op a b` is just `b -> a`, and has a `Divisible` instance for any `Monoid a`.

To get the behavior of your instance, we can use `Ap m a`, which provides a `Monoid` with `mappend = liftA2 (<>)` and `mempty = pure mempty` for any `Applicative m` and `Monoid a`.

```
type ReaderDual a m b = Op (Ap m a) b
```